# Update column in sql table based on distinct values of other columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a sql table with the following sample data:

```
Id Test_Id Strategy_Name Symbol_Name Test_Start_Date Test_End_Date Test_Interval P1 P2 P3

11 0       5x5           ICC         2012-01-01      2012-12-31    Hourly    69 18 2    
12 0       5x5           ICC         2012-01-01      2012-12-31    Hourly    5  25 2    
13 0       5x5           ICC         2012-01-01      2012-12-31    Hourly    6  25 2    
14 0       5x5           ICC         2012-01-01      2012-12-31    Hourly    2  25 2    
15 0       5x5           ICC         2011-01-01      2011-12-31    Hourly    2  25 2
```

I want to run an update query which will assign a unique value to the test_id column based on distinct strategy_name, symbol_name, test_interval, P1, P2, P3.
So the test_id for all the rows above will be unique except for row 4 and 5 because they have same values except for the test_start_date and test_end_date, hence they will have same test_id.

How to go about doing this, can you just run an update query or a stored procedure to auto increment the test id value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to create ids using `ROW_NUMBER()`. I don't know if this is the easiest way to fill in the ids in your case, but it should work.

It may work with a single update, without temp table, but sometimes I find it easier to split operations in smaller steps.

Create a temp table with ids

```
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by strategy_name, symbol_name, test_interval, P1, P2, P3 asc) as id,
    strategy_name, symbol_name, test_interval, P1, P2, P3
INTO #ids
FROM [table]
GROUP BY strategy_name, symbol_name, test_interval, P1, P2, P3
```

Fill in the ids

```
UPDATE [table]
SET test_id = (select id from #ids where 
  [table].strategy_name = #ids.strategy_name, 
  and [table].symbol_name = #ids.symbol_name, 
  and [table].test_interval = #ids.test_interval, 
  and [table].P1 = #ids.P1, 
  and [table].P2 = #ids.P2, 
  and [table].P3 = #ids.P3)
```